# deserialize RecognizedForm object from json (Azure Form Recognizer Python SDK)

Tags: python, json, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I need to deserialize json-serialized Azure Form Recognizer results into python FormRecognizer objects (from azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.1.0b1 package), and I do not see any sort of api to perform this deserialization.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the challenges you are having with the json response that makes you want to convert to the SDK object? The SDK doesn't currently provide a public surface for deserializing the REST response to a RecognizedForm.

Comment: I have inherited a large body of python code that takes a RecognizedForm object and performs further processing/parsing on it and a database of json-serialized RecognizedForm objects.  Some of these json-serialized RecognizedForm objects have been successfully parsed/processed and some have not.  I need to create RecognizedForm objects from this serialized data so that I can run the unparsed  objects through the code that further processes/parses RecognizedForm objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you are parsing, if you just need to access `RecognizedForm` attributes and don't need a true `RecognizedForm` object (in other words, just the shape of a `RecognizedForm` object), this might work for you:

```
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace
recognized_form = json.loads(recognized_form_json, object_hook=lambda fields: SimpleNamespace(**fields))
```

Otherwise, we can manually deserialize it back to a `RecognizedForm`. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kristapratico/83f8fbb7cf25563491e796c23ae5332c) for an example (not fully tested).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the gist, that is very helpful (and yes, it does need access to property attributes)!